# Remove particular class's completion handler from array

Tags: swift3, completionhandler

I have implemented one method of completion handler which fetch data from server.
While one request is in progress, this method may be called multiple time by any other class and I want to notify all once data is received from server without sending multiple request.

To achieve this I am adding up completion handlers in thread safe array.
But I want to remove particular completion handler if caller class doesn't exists in memory when data is received from server.

Ex - If controller's **viewDidDisAppear()** gets called. I want to removed its handler.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Why not use NSNotification instead of those completion handlers?

Comment: I was thining to solve this by using completionHandler. If I don't find any way will use NSNotification. Performance wise which approach will be better?